# Howto call MessageBox in dllmain

Tags: c++, windows, dll

I'm creating a little dll to use in a DLL-INJECTION POC (proof-of-concept). I'm using codeblocks' c++ ide.

My dll's main (dllmain) looks like this:

```
BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    MessageBox(0, "myfirstdll loaded", "SUCCESS STATUS", MB_OK);
    switch (fdwReason)
    {
        case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
            // attach to process
            // return FALSE to fail DLL load
            break;
        case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
            // detach from process
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
            // attach to thread
            break;

        case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
            // detach from thread
            break;
    }
    return TRUE; // succesful
}
```

Now, when I load the dll (using LoadLibrary) from a client program (hopefull, it loads!), my message box doesn't pop. This is quiet frustrating, since I'm doing a poc. I know about security issues that prevail when we do kernel32.dll, etc.-intensive business in dllmain, but then, my problem here is not security; i simply need to pop a message box right from within dllmain.

So, how can i make my message box pop when the dll is loaded ?

Comment: Please format your code.

Comment: Check `LoadLibrary` result, probably DLL wasn't loaded.

Comment: Thanks for the remark; that was dirty indeed.

Comment: @tenfour, please make this an answer.

Comment: Thanks. But, the dll is loaded indeed, since I get to use a function exported by the dll (the said function works with no troubles). But I can't get message box popped in dllmain.

Comment: Use OutputDebugString() and SysInternals' DebugView utility.

Comment: probably message box is calling LoadLibrary. Do what Hans says.

Answer (score 6):

[See this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834508/usage-limitations-during-the-dllmain-attach-and-detach-process) to read about the huge number of limitations in `DllMain`. It's not just security problems. Anything exported by user32 falls into this category.

In other words, you cannot use `MessageBox` in `DllMain`. Use something like [`OutputDebugString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362.aspx) instead, which is in kernel32 and does not display any UI.

Comment: a bit late , but why can't you?

Comment: @Agguro: Because UI stuff is allowed to depend on loading DLLs, and you can't load DLLs from DllMain.

Answer (score 2):

There's a lot of useful stuff that just can not be done in DllMain. Read all relating articles in [Raymond Chen's blog](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&q=dllmain%20site:devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) for more info. Can't even delay execution with `SetTimer`, because that function is in user32.dll, and that library may not be loaded yet.

Comment: Thanks. It's such a pity then. I'm looking at the proposed article.

Comment: OK, the article was quite helpful. Now after roaming awhile, I solved my problem by adding the line:

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE, DWORD, LPVOID);

to my dll's main header (main.h), thus 'exporting DllMain' \L/.
Now I get my POC popup (notwithstanding the security dangers, but then I'm coding an exploit, not some nice app for a beautiful client :)).

Thanks a lot.