# C DLL Injection failing

Tags: c++, c, winapi, dll

I am trying to inject a DLL into notepad and make it show a MessageBox, but nothing happens at all. i'm new to this, but i am sure it was supposed to be working.

I am currently using this code for the DLL file (Dllinj.dll):

```cpp
#include <windows.h>

DWORD WINAPI MyThreadFunction(LPVOID lpParam) {
    MessageBoxA(NULL, "Dll in the thread.", "DLL Thread", MB_OK);
    
    return 0;
}



__declspec(dllexport) void CreateThreadInDLL() {
    HANDLE hThread = CreateThread(NULL, 0, MyThreadFunction, NULL, 0, NULL);

    if (hThread == NULL) {
        MessageBoxA(NULL, "Error creating thread", "DLL Thread", MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    } else {
        WaitForSingleObject(hThread, INFINITE);


        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved) {
    switch (fdwReason) {
         case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:{
            CreateThreadInDLL();
         }
    }
    return TRUE;
}
```

And compiling with this line:

```
gcc dllinj.cpp -o dllinj.dll -shared
```

i've tried [nefarius injector](https://github.com/nefarius/Injector). and it returned error [Call to LoadLibraryW in remote process failed.](https://github.com/nefarius/Injector/issues/9), but i've checked the process architecture and i know it's 64 bits already and i am compiling to 64 bits.

I readed [this post about the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15624286/dll-injection-failed), but as the solution was simply changing IDE, i couldn't fix it by myself as i am not using any. and yes, i've seen the answer saying that MessageBox doesn't works inside DllMain function, so that's why it doesn't shows up, but in my case the dll isn't even injecting in the first place.

Also tried this injector code i found on [this page](https://cocomelonc.github.io/tutorial/2021/09/20/malware-injection-2.html). it does infact return an error, but i am not sure what i've done wrong here.

(Updated)

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>

char evilDLL[] = "C:\\Users\\ACER\\Desktop\\tcc\\Dllinj.dll";
unsigned int evilLen = sizeof(evilDLL) + 1;

void HandleError(const char* message) {
    perror(message);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

void LastErrorBox()
{
    printf("eeee");
    LPWSTR pBuffer = NULL;
    int ret = FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, GetLastError(), 0, (LPWSTR)&pBuffer, 0, 0);
    if (!(ret && pBuffer))
    {
        MessageBoxW(0, pBuffer, L"failed to read error", 0);
        return;
    }

    MessageBoxW(0, pBuffer, L"", 0);
    LocalFree(pBuffer);
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    DWORD ipthr = 10008; // process id  

    HANDLE ph = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, ipthr);
    if (ph == NULL) {
        HandleError("Error opening process");
    }

    LPVOID rb = VirtualAllocEx(ph, NULL, evilLen, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
    if (rb == NULL) {
        CloseHandle(ph);
        HandleError("Error allocating memory in the remote process");
    }

    if (!WriteProcessMemory(ph, rb, evilDLL, evilLen, NULL)) {
        CloseHandle(ph);
        VirtualFreeEx(ph, rb, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        HandleError("Error writing to remote process memory");
    }

    HMODULE hKernel32 = GetModuleHandle("Kernel32");
    if (hKernel32 == NULL) {
        CloseHandle(ph);
        VirtualFreeEx(ph, rb, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        HandleError("Error getting handle to Kernel32");
    }

    FARPROC lb = GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "LoadLibraryW");
    if (lb == NULL) {
        CloseHandle(ph);
        VirtualFreeEx(ph, rb, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
        HandleError("Error getting address of LoadLibraryW");
    }

    
    printf("%lu",ipthr);

    HANDLE rt = CreateRemoteThread(ph, NULL, 0,
                                          (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lb,
                                          rb, 0, &ipthr);
    LastErrorBox();



    if (rt == NULL) {
        CloseHandle(ph);
        VirtualFreeEx(ph, rb, 0, MEM_RELEASE);

        HandleError("Error creating remote thread");
       
    }

    // Wait for the remote thread to finish
    WaitForSingleObject(rt, INFINITE);


    CloseHandle(rt);
    VirtualFreeEx(ph, rb, 0, MEM_RELEASE);
    CloseHandle(ph);

    return 0;
}
```

Compiled with this line:

```
g++ -O2 injector.cpp -o injector.exe -s -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Wno-write-strings -fno-exceptions -fmerge-all-constants -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -fpermissive
```

An ran with this line:

```
injector.exe 10008
```

I got the following output:
`Error creating remote thread: No error`

Also, `LastErrorBox();` gives me a messagebox saying "Invalid identifier".

Yes, i am sure the process PID is 10008, which i checked at process hacker and process manager.

I also tried using process hacker to see if my dll was injected into notepad with the code above but i didn't found any dll named "Dllinj.dll" either.

[image: Process hacker memory view of notepad.exe]

I also tried cheat engine dll injector, but i got this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bJGFW.png)

All of this leads me to belive the problem is in the dll compilation process or the code itself, though i am not sure what is the problem.

I am new to this kind of low level access into windows kernel, so please dont be rude with me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Any of those Windows API calls could be failing in the injector but none of the return values are ever checked. Add error checking.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thank you, i've added some error checks with ChatGPT and i got this error "Error creating remote thread", i'll update the post soon with the new code.

Comment: "error checks with ChatGPT" ... Don't use ChatGPT. That thing is completely useless for any serious program (even beginner programming it struggles on).

Comment: @ChrisMM i agree with you, i had many problems with ChatGPT before, but at least for these error checks, it looks alright to me and seems to be working, i hope it helps.

Comment: Not enough ... You may have `if` statements, but you're not actually checking the errors. Read the proper documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread) which says what you should check if the function returns `NULL`. You're also calling `WaitForSingleObject` _then_ checking the return value ... Should be the other way around.

Comment: @ChrisMM Well, indeed my if statements are checking if the functions returns NULL as i know. i also fixed to check first then use ``WaitForSingleObject``, thank you.

Comment: You need to call `GetLastError` right after your call fails.

Comment: @ElderBug You need to call `GetLastError()` *at all*. OP never even calls `GetLastError()`! `perror` prints `errno`, not `GetLastError()`.

Comment: Fun fact; despite appearances this question is the rare case of should have both C++ and C tags.

Comment: @ElderBug You need to call `GetLastError()` **exactly** when the documentation tells you to. Look up the documentation for [`CreateMutexW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-createmutexw) to find an example where `GetLastError()` returns valid information upon success. Likewise, look up [`CreateDCW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-createdcw) for an example where `GetLastError()` **never** returns valid information. The *"Call `GetLastError()` on failure"* mantra gets kinda old.

Comment: The DLL code is creating a local thread and then waiting on it, all in the context of DllMain. That is a guaranteed deadlock. You can't wait on the thread in DllMain, that is blocking the thread from calling DllMain with the DLL_THREAD_ATTACH notification. [Does creating a thread from DllMain deadlock or doesn't it?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070904-00/?p=25283)

Answer (score 1):

First concern is about following code:

```cpp
HANDLE rt = CreateRemoteThread(ph, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lb, rb, 0, NULL);
```

Last argument should be a valid pointer to a thread id,

```
DWORD dwThreadId;
HANDLE rt = CreateRemoteThread(ph, NULL, 0, (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)lb, rb, 0, &dwThreadId);
```

It is CreateRemoteThread failing, so according to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createremotethread) call GetLastError/FormatMessage to get more detailed information.

Second concern is about how you call MessageBox in your dll:

```
MessageBox(NULL,"Injected!",MB_OK);
```

According to [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-messagebox) this function takes four parameters instead of three. Did it even compile? I would expect failure there. Did you try to execute this dll in your own program first? Normally the dll logic should be added into DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH or DLL_THREAD_ATTACH.

As your program is OS Windows specific, consider using VisualStudio.

About following code:

```cpp
LPVOID rb = VirtualAllocEx(ph, NULL, evilLen, MEM_RESERVE | MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
```

For arguments passed to function PAGE_READWRITE it is much enough.
About this  `sizeof(evilDLL) + 1`, sizeof is not strlen. It takes the real size of the buffer and doesn't count non null characters. So, +1 it is at least redundant, not to say wrong. It overruns the buffer of evilDLL, which normally is a bad practice.

And consider there is no point in calling GetModuleHandle and GetProcAddress. These will **not** be executed in context of remote process, instead will be taken locally.

As LoadLibrary already had an address, lowing code should be enough:

```cpp
HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0,
                                        (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA,
                                        pvProcMem, 0, &dwThreadId);
```

The above syntax for pointer to function LoadLibraryA works ok in VisualStudio, but this might require different syntax in g++.
Or if you would like to call the unicode version of LoadLibrary:

```cpp
   HANDLE hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hProcess, 0, 0,
                                          (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryW,
                                          pvProcMem, 0, &dwThreadId);
```

UPDATE 1:

```cpp
void LastErrorBox()
{
    LPWSTR pBuffer = NULL;
    int ret = FormatMessageW(FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, 0, GetLastError(), 0, (LPWSTR)&pBuffer, 0, 0);
    if (!(ret && pBuffer))
    {
        MessageBoxW(0, pBuffer, L"failed to read error", 0);
        return;
    }

    MessageBoxW(0, pBuffer, L"", 0);
    LocalFree(pBuffer);
}
```

Comment: Hello, i think i've fixed most of what you've mentioned, though i am not sure how to use GetLastError, it is not returning anything when i print it, i've updated the post so you can take a look. i am still with the same error than before tho, the main problem is that the DLL itself seems to not be working.

Comment: OP used a char array rather than a pointer but it's moot because VirtaulAlloc allocates in multiples of 4k.

Comment: And yes he does have to call GetProcAddress for LoadLibraryA; this works because kernel32 really is guaranteed to be in the same address in all processes; and otherwise there's no way to get the address in target process.

Comment: `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA` actually doesn't work; this gives the address of the relocation trampoline within your executable not the real address.

Comment: @Yeet Please for GetLastError, it should be used with FormatMessage. Check UPDATE1 in my answer.  You can copy/paste that in your code completely

Comment: @Joshua as you say, as it is guaranteed to be the same in all processes, which makes the calling to GetProcAddress redundant and pointless. The function pointer from current process is enough, as it comes when windows.h #included. That is exactly the reason why the reason (LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA will work.

Comment: GCC generates `(LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE)LoadLibraryA`  `lea r9, [rel LoadLibraryA]` where `LoadLibraryA: jmp [rel +6] dq __imp_LoadLibraryA` and the `dq` instruction is fixed up the the loader, not the `lea` instruction so it doesn't work.

Comment: @Joshua What is the reason to use such an exotic compiler? I already pointed, VisualStudio should be used. Moreover, this code is not meant to work on Linux. And VisualStudio can be used for free.

Comment: OP used GCC, and VisualStudio is the exotic compiler. GCC is in general much better; and this optimization by the compiler is right unless you are doing DLL injection.

Comment: @armagedescu i added you code and i received a messagebox saying "invalid identifier"!

Comment: @Yeet call ShowLastError immediately after CreaterRemoteThread. It may give different error. Also, consider adding DllMain into your dll, and put your code into DLL_THREAD_ATTACH or DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH, can't tell right away which one exactly. Your DLL will not execute just because you added some functions into it. The loading process knows only about DllMain if it is present.

Comment: @Yeet also regardless of all biases, I would strongly suggest using VisualStudio. Because there is no way you run it under Linux, so no reason to use gcc.

Comment: @armagedescu , responding 2 of your comments, i applied the changes you suggested (+ updated the post) and now i received "Denied access", though i am running it from an admin console, weird. about visualstudio, i cant really because my computer cant run it, so GCC is the most advanced developing ambient i can have unfortunately, but regardless of everything i appreciate your help :)

Comment: @Yeet: It's almost like your build outputs are 32 bit.

Comment: @Joshua how do i ensure they are 64 bit? now i am not sure.. every line i used is mentioned in the main post, THOUGH there's a thing i didn't mentioned is that when i use the flag -m64 to compile i receive "sorry, unimplemented: 64-bit mode not compiled in", but i didn't think much of it and just ignored, should this flag work?

Comment: @Joshua lmao guess what

Comment: @Yeet: To check if you've finally got it right, put this in your code: `printf("%d\n", (int)(sizeof(void*)));` -- note that we can't tell if `gcc` is the 32 or 64 bit compiler without looking at your system.

Comment: @Joshua this prints out "8", also, now finally with Mingw-64 installed, i tried compiling the DLL with -m64 flag and now it pops up a message "Couldn't find specified module", if i try to inject with cheat engine it crashes the app, but at least it is actually injecting!

Comment: @Joshua this is not **sizeof (void*)**, it is sizeof constant char array, which will give the number of chars, including ending zero char 
```char evilDLL[] = "C:\\Users\\ACER\\Desktop\\tcc\\Dllinj.dll";
unsigned int evilLen = sizeof(evilDLL) + 1;``` (+ one more here)

Comment: @armagedescu: I told him to produce `sizeof(void*)` to verify it really was a 64 bit build.

Answer (score 1):

As it came out i was just dumb, i thought default MingW already compiled to 64 bit executables, but as it turned out, i was compiling to 32 bits the entire time, i finally downloaded the MingW-64 and the simple snippets from [this](https://cocomelonc.github.io/tutorial/2021/09/20/malware-injection-2.html) site worked perfectly! also the messagebox does infact work inside DllMain, for some reason.

Thanks for everyone who tried to help, and i am much sorry for wasting everyone's time.

Comment: I'm glad you have got your solution and thank for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.