# MessageBox not being called from DllMain after Injection

Tags: c, winapi, dll-injection, w3wp

**Goal**

I am trying to `inject an x64 DLL` into the `w3wp.exe` process (IIS worker process) in order to debug my DLL with Visual Studio.

**What I have done**

I am using [Extreme Injector V3](https://www.extreme-injector.com/download/) to do this. After selecting the debug build of my DLL and the w3wp.exe process from the process list in Extreme Injector, I click on Inject and am greeted with a MessageBox telling me that the injection completed successfully.

**What I expect**

I should see a `MessageBoxA(0, "injected", 0, 0)` from the DllMain. However, I don't see no such thing!

**The code of the DLL**

```
int __stdcall DllMain(HMODULE base, unsigned long reason, void* args)
{
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `MessageBox()` (and any other function from `user32.dll`) is not safe to call from `DllMain()`.  See [Dynamic-Link Library Best Practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dynamic-link-library-best-practices).

Comment: You can use `OutputDebugString()` and dbgview.exe if you want confirmation that your injection was successful.

Comment: Why would you expect to see a message box? The code posted doesn't call `MessageBox` (ignoring that you cannot safely do this anyway).

Comment: @JonathanPotter I replaced `MessageBox` with `OutputDebugStringA("test")` and open `DbgView.exe` as admin. I don't see "test" in the DbgView.exe output. Why is this?

Comment: I guess your injection is failing.

Comment: I can see the output by using `OutputDebugString` + `dbgview.exe`. Can you confirm your injection success?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Howto call MessageBox in dllmain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8377569/howto-call-messagebox-in-dllmain)

Answer (score 0):

> What I expect
>   I should see a MessageBoxA(0, "injected", 0, 0) from the DllMain. However, I don't see no such thing!

Your code doesn't call MessageBox(), it just returns 1 on injection.

Despite being not recommended, if you're just doing it for experiment purposes the code should look like:

```cpp
int __stdcall DllMain(HMODULE base, unsigned long reason, void* args)
{
    if (reason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
        MessageBoxA(0, "injected", 0, 0);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

If that doesn't work you need to try a different injector, make sure your injector is running as administrator.

If w3wp.exe is running as NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM you may need higher permissions