# "this program has stopped working" when application close (W8 Pro 64bits)

Tags: .net-3.5, windows-8, 64-bit

I have a program developed using VB.NET 2008 (NET Framework 3.5). Compiled  for x86.

Now I have installed this software on W8 Pro 64bits computer. the software runs fine, except when I close the app. After close it,warning is displayed: "the program has stopped working".

> Event Id::1000
>
> Faulting application name: XXXXX.exe, versión:1.0.4689.31692, marca de tiempo: 0x5093f694
>
> Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, versión: 6.2.9200.16451, marca de tiempo: 0x50988950
>
> Exception code: 0xc0020001 Fault offset: 0x00014b32

This software runs fine on all previous versions of windows8  : W7, Vista, 2008, 2003, XP...Both: 32 and 64 bits.

I have tried on computer with W8 Consumer Preview - 32bits and runs fine. no warning displayed.

I've tried the 'compatibility mode' but still shows the same message

Any idea to solve it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [0xC0020001: The string binding is invalid. - Only occurring in WPF](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835748/0xc0020001-the-string-binding-is-invalid-only-occurring-in-wpf)

Comment: we are also facing the issue, when looked at the event log we see the following error message

Comment: Faulting application name: xxxx.exe, version: 1.1.2.0, time stamp: 0x520b6bc0
Faulting module name: KERNELBASE.dll, version: 6.2.9200.16451, time stamp: 0x50988aa6
Exception code: 0xc0020001
Fault offset: 0x000000000003811c
Faulting process id: 0x21bc
Faulting application start time: 0x01ce98e2c92c1370
Faulting application path: xxxxx.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\system32\KERNELBASE.dll
Report Id: 0a88dab9-04d6-11e3-bef1-e453a6124328
Faulting package full name: ...